# FileUtils.mkdir_p support for wildcards in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have for example directory structure like this:

```
./DIRECTORY/PROJECT_A/cars/
./DIRECTORY/PROJECT_B/planes/
./DIRECTORY/PROJECT_C/bikes/
```

I would like to recourse through them using wildcards and create other directory's, like this:

```
Dir['/DIRECTORY/PROJECT_*/*/'].each do FileUtils.mkdir_p 'TheNewDirectory'.
```

It seems "FileUtils" doesn't support wildcards.

I'm doing the same for creation of files on this way:

```
  Dir['/DIRECTORY/PROJECT_*/*/'].each do |dir|
    File.new File.join(dir, 'myFile.txt'), 'w+'
  end
```

So I would like to do the same but for creation of directories. Any idea?

Comment: @Wand Maker: Have edited my question. So I would like to do the same with directories as I do with the creation of files like shown in the snipet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create directory, you need to specify full path of new directory using the current folder name:

```
Dir['/DIRECTORY/PROJECT_*/*/'].each do |f| 
  FileUtils.mkdir_p "#{f}/TheNewDirectory" if File.directory?(f) 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

FileUtils is a module. It doesn't make sense to claim that a module "does not use wildcards".

Moreover, you are using only the function mkdir_p from FileUtils, and do not use any wildcard in its argument, so what you say, doesn't apply to your case either.

What happened is, that your are iterating through all the directories entries created by your *Dir[...]* expression, but then don't use the actual directory! A first step to write this better would be

```
Dir['/DIRECTORY/PROJECT_*/*/'].each { |d| FileUtils.mkdir_p("#{d}/TheNewDirectory") }
```

This works however only if it is guaranteed that d never takes the value of a plain file, and of course you can run this code only once (because the second time, you would obviously create directories of the form /DIRECTORY/PROJECT_FOO/BAR/TheNewDirectory/TheNewDirectory. I would therefore check, for the safe side, that it indeed makes sense to create the directory, before doing it.